# Angular displacement after full rotation

Tags: terminology, definition, rotation, displacement

I was wondering is why [angular displacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_displacement) isn't $0$ after $n$ full rotations?

Comment: You need to provide more context here. At least a reference or something. Besides the obvious displacement = n × 360°.

Comment: Have you read the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_displacement) of angular displacement?

Comment: Yes but it seems counter intuitive. Why is displacement different rotationally than linearly?

Comment: It does seem to be an inconsistent use of the word "displacement".   It wouldn't be the first time such a thing has happened.

Comment: I would have thought there would be a reason that is isn't 0, I wouldn't think the incongruity is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, complex numbers and rotation are intimately related.

After rotation $\theta$ in the complex plane, the number $1$ becomes $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$. Although $e^{i(2n\pi)} = 1 = \cos(0) + i\sin(0)$, you actually moved by $\theta$ and not by $0$.

If you rotated something by $\pi$, you could say the angle is now $-\pi$ - but you would never say that you rotated by a negative angle when you rotated by a positive angle.

So angular displacement is not like linear displacement. It's not enough to know where you ended up: "it's the journey, not the destination". In that sense, rotation is wiser than translation...